# Can't use constants when trying to connect to database in the other file

Tags: php, mysql, database, constants, undefined

I have a file called config.php in which i defined 4 constants:

```
<?php

define('HOST','localhost');
define('USER','root');
define('PASSWORD','');
define('DATABASE','some_database');

?>
```

What I want to do is call this script with request_once function inside the other php file called database.php which will use the constant from this file for connecting

```
<?php
  require_once('config.php');
  $connect = mysql_connect(HOST,USER,PASSWORD);
  $select_db = mysql_select_db(DATABASE);
?>
```

What i get returned is that the host,user,password and database are not defined. Why is that? This is a sample simplified code i used for connection but the essence of the problem is here. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you tried to just echo the variables to ensure your script is properly reading the other file? Could it be the wrong path? Just guess. Btw, `mysql` commands are deprecated for security reasons in favor of the new `mysqli` commands.

Comment: The both files lay in the same directory and I checked about a dozen times if the filenames are correctly spelled and so on :/

Comment: If they're not defined then there is something prevents `config.php` to be included. Check your file names and make sure there is no error in `config.php`.

Comment: How exactly do you find that the constants are undefined? Do you really get the `Notice: Use of undefined constant HOST - assumed 'HOST'` message?

Comment: @Alvaro he won't get it if he has not `error_reporting(E_ALL)` declared before

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario Yes I do get that error :)

Comment: @DevGuy - Then, next time you get an error message please paste it in the question. Error messages are not there just to annoy you, they provide useful information to troubleshoot an issue.

Comment: I know this is very old, although you should be using .env() for managing environment variables, great for when working with git, developing locally and deploying via git to server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP by default DO NOT SHOW Notices of undefined constants. So if you use a undefined constant PHP would simple treat that one as a string. For example,

```
<?php
//define('__TEST__', 'foo');

print __TEST__; //Will print __TEST__ and raise E_NOTICE if it's enabled
```

if you uncomment above `define()` PHP will print `foo` instead and won't raise a notice.

Personally I would suggest you to make a bit deeper test:

0) Declare `error_reporting(E_ALL)` in config.php
1) Check whether file exists and it readable before you include this
2) Check whether constants are actually defined before you use them

Finally, It would like this:

File: config.php

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);

define('HOST','localhost');
define('USER','root');
define('PASSWORD','');
define('DATABASE','some_database');
```

File: dbconnection.php

```
<?php

//require() will produce FATAL error if inclusion fails, so we're OK
require_once('config.php'); 


if ( defined('HOST') && defined('USER') && defined('PASSWORD') && defined('DATABASE') ){

 $connect = mysql_connect(HOST,USER,PASSWORD);
 $select_db = mysql_select_db(DATABASE);

} else {

  trigger_error('Some constants are missing', E_USER_ERROR);
}
```

Comment: @devguy - You should post a comment on how exactly this answer helped you fix your issue. As it is now, this question is of little use for future Stack Overflow readers.

Answer (score 0):

you can try Include() just to see if it makes a difference. also if you are working on a local machine, you may want to use  :

```
require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . "/config.php");
```

You should look into MYSQLI or PDO as the mysql functions are depreciated now:

```
 define("DB_HOST", "");
 define("DB_USERNAME", "");
 define("DB_PASSWORD", "");
 define("DB_NAME", "");

    $Mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
        if ($Mysqli->connect_errno)
        {
            echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $Mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $Mysqli->connect_error;
            $Mysqli->close();
        }
```